# Is [WkInterfaceDevice addCachedImage:] Thread Safe?

Tags: ios, watchkit

Can I add an image to the WkInterfaceDevice image cache from a background thread? I couldn't find any documentation if the API was safe to use in a background thread.

Thanks!
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an Apple employee on the Developer Forums, you can use addCachedImage: from a background thread. In fact, that's how I use it in my app.